# List of visited pages per logged in user

Tags: google-analytics

I use custom google analytics variables to track the user ID of the visitor.
What I want is to see which pages a user visits after he signups to my website.

To achieve this I try to create a custom report about which pages a certain user ID visits.
I can't get this to work, on the custom report system I cannot select the correct filters & settings.

I hope anyone here has experience in doing this and can help me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics won't show you this information at scale.  It might work for 1-2 visitors, but Google Analytics purposefully restricts you from seeing individual visitor details.

Your best bet is to use a software product so you don't violate any privacy restrictions.

Comment: If you save a local copy of your Google Analytics tracking requests, you can process them in Angelfish:
http://support.angelfishstats.com/entries/42575637-How-To-Process-Google-Analytics-Data-with-Angelfish

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into Universal Analytics. Much more centered around users - http://online-behavior.com/analytics/universal